# Why `null >= 0 && null <= 0` but not `null == 0`?

Tags: javascript, null, comparison, equality

I had to write a routine that increments the value of a variable by 1 if its type is `number` and assigns 0 to the variable if not, where the variable is initially `null` or `undefined`.

The first implementation was `v >= 0 ? v += 1 : v = 0` because I thought anything not a number would make an arithmetic expression false, but it was wrong since `null >= 0` is evaluated to true. Then I learned `null` behaves like 0 and the following expressions are all evaluated to true.

- `null >= 0 && null <= 0`
- `!(null < 0 || null > 0)`
- `null + 1 === 1`
- `1 / null === Infinity`
- `Math.pow(42, null) === 1`

Of course, `null` is not 0. `null == 0` is evaluated to false. This makes the seemingly tautological expression `(v >= 0 && v <= 0) === (v == 0)` false.

Why is `null` like 0, although it is not actually 0?

Comment: He is talking about Javascript. Your example is in PHP. In PHP operator== compares values in a special way. You can make some really crazy comparisons like "10" == "1e1" (which is true). If you used operator===, you would get a whole different result because it checks whether the type matches as well as the value. Check this link out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The PHP '==' operator really does work in a "special" way.

Comment: If your requirement was to start counting at 1 instead of 0, there's a really terse way to increment counters that are initially either `null` or `undefined`: `c = -~c // Results in 1 for null/undefined; increments if already a number`

Comment: `undefined` is a variable value, for variables that have not been initialized. `null`, on the other hand, is an empty object value, and should not be mixed with numbers. `null` should not be combined with numbers, so null should not have to behave like numbers.

Comment: @AtesGoral - terse, but non-obvious. Worth reminding people that whenever doing something non-obvious, to please add a comment explaining what the code does. In most situations, I would consider it a "premature optimization", given that it trades clarity for a miniscule performance gain.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Your real question seem to be:

Why:

```
null >= 0; // true
```

But:

```
null == 0; // false
```

What really happens is that the *Greater-than-or-equal Operator*  (`>=`), performs type coercion ([`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)), with a *hint* type of `Number`, actually all the relational operators have this behavior.

`null` is treated in a special way by the *Equals Operator* (`==`). In a brief, it only *coerces* to `undefined`:

```
null == null; // true
null == undefined; // true
```

Value such as `false`, `''`, `'0'`, and `[]` are subject to numeric type coercion, all of them coerce to zero.

You can see the inner details of this process in the [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5).

In Summary:

- Relational Comparison: if both values are not type String, `ToNumber` is called on both. This is the same as adding a `+` in front, which for null coerces to `0`.
- Equality Comparison: only calls `ToNumber` on Strings, Numbers, and Booleans.

Comment: Hi CMS, as per your explanation null primitive is 0,so 0>=0 returns true and == is returning false.but as per the ecma algorithm If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.then in this it should return true.please explain me

Comment: to me the answer does not provide an *answer* - `null is treated in a special way by the Equals Operator (==). In a brief, it only coerces to undefined:` - and what? Can you explain, why `null >= 0`? :)

Comment: @bharathmuppa @andrey-deineko:

The rest of CMS's answer is here:

[The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5)

which explains in point 3. that if both values are not type String, ToNumber is called on both. This is the same as adding a `+` in front, which for null coerces to `0`. 

Equality only calls ToNumber on Strings, Numbers, and Booleans.

Comment: Good description, but I don't like it.  In any language (x == 0 || x > 0) should be equivalent to (x >= 0).  javascript is a stupid language.

Comment: It's simply a bug in the spec really (because mathematically it's wrong) and there is nothing to do about it since millions of websites relies on null comparisons ^^'

Comment: Shouldn't it be, if both values are not number, ToNumber is called on them, you have written if both values are not string, ToNumber is called on them.

Answer (score 22):

I'd like to extend the question to further improve visibility of the problem:

```
null >= 0; //true
null <= 0; //true
null == 0; //false
null > 0;  //false
null < 0;  //false
```

It just makes no sense. Like human languages, these things need be learned by heart.

Comment: As described above it can be explained with just an exception as how == treats  null, otherwise in all cases null is being converted into 0 by using Number(nulll)

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript has both strict and type–converting comparisons

`null >= 0;` is true
but
`(null==0)||(null>0)` is false

`null <= 0;` is true but `(null==0)||(null<0)` is false

`"" >= 0` is also true

For relational abstract comparisons (<= , >=), the operands are first converted to primitives, then to the same type, before comparison.

`typeof null returns "object"`

When type is object javascript tries to stringify the object (i.e null)
the following steps are taken ([ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive)):

1. If `PreferredType` was not passed, let `hint` be "default".
2. Else if `PreferredType` is `hint` String, let `hint` be "string".
3. Else `PreferredType` is `hint` Number, let `hint` be "number".
4. Let `exoticToPrim` be `GetMethod(input, @@toPrimitive)`.
5. `ReturnIfAbrupt(exoticToPrim)`.
6. If `exoticToPrim` is not undefined, then 
   a) Let result be `Call(exoticToPrim, input, «hint»)`.
   b) `ReturnIfAbrupt(result)`.
   c) If `Type(result)` is not Object, return result.
   d) Throw a TypeError exception.
7. If `hint` is "default", let `hint` be "number".
8. Return `OrdinaryToPrimitive(input,hint)`.

The allowed values for hint are "default", "number", and "string". Date objects, are unique among built-in ECMAScript object in that they treat "default" as being equivalent to "string". 
**All other built-in ECMAScript objects treat "default" as being equivalent to "number"**. ([ECMAScript 20.3.4.45](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive))

So I think `null` converts to 0.

Answer (score 10):

```
console.log( null > 0 );  // (1) false
console.log( null == 0 ); // (2) false
console.log( null >= 0 ); // (3) true
```

Mathematically, that’s strange. The last result states that "null is greater than or equal to zero", so in one of the comparisons above it must be true, but they are both false.

The reason is that an equality check `==` and comparisons `> < >= <=` work differently. Comparisons convert null to a number, treating it as `0`. That’s why (3) `null >= 0` is `true` and (1) `null > 0` is `false`.

On the other hand, the equality check `==` for `undefined` and `null` is defined such that, without any conversions, they equal each other and don’t equal anything else. That’s why (2) `null == 0` is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem !!.
Currently my only solution is to separate.

```
var a = null;
var b = undefined;

if (a===0||a>0){ } //return false  !work!
if (b===0||b>0){ } //return false  !work!

//but 
if (a>=0){ } //return true !
```

Comment: It might be clearer to instead do: `if (a!=null && a>=0)`. This clarifies the reason for not simply doing `>=` by itself: "a might be null (or undefined, which is also '== null')".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way to check `x >= 0` is `!(x < 0)` In that way make sense the response.