# Javascript comparison question (null >= 0)

Tags: javascript, comparison

How should I understand these?

```
null>0
> false

null==0
> false

null>=0
> true
```

Comment: Web Inspector console of Safari 5  (most recent version)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0 - has some more interesting answers though CMS's answers in both are the best reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The relational operators (`>=` and `<=`), perform type coercion ([`ToPrimitive`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.1)), with a hint type of `Number`, all the relational operators present have this behavior.

You can see the inner details of this process in the [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.5).

On the other hand, the [Equals operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.1) (`==`), if an operand is `null` it only returns `true` if the other is either `null` or `undefined`, no numeric type coercion is made.

```
null == undefined; // true
null == null; // true
```

Check the inner details of this process in the [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.5).

Recommended articles:

- [`typeof`, `==` and `===`](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/post/typeof-and-friends)
- [Notes on ECMAScript Equality Operators](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-2-ecmascript-equality-operators/)

Comment: OK. ">", "<" evaluate null as 0. "==" does not. Thanks.

Comment: Other interesting thing is that a >= b is not evaluated as ((a > b) || (a == b)) but as ! (a < b). That explains why null >= 0 is not same as  > or ==.

Answer (score 6):

The relative comparison operators imply a numeric context, so in those cases (`>`, `>=`) the `null` is converted to a number (zero).

In the `==` case, however, both values are treated as boolean values, and Javascript doesn't think that `null` should be equal to any other "falsy" values.  It's kind-of weird. The equality algorithm for `==` has a bunch of special cases, and `null` is one of those. It's only `==` to itself and `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

When null is used in a numeric experession it evalutes to 0, that explains your > and >= cases.

== is more subtle. Informally, null is not the same as zero, so it kind of makes sense.

Comment: [This](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8) is a very very useful link to understanding the steps taken in using these operators. Still doesn't explain the crazy logic, but meh...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!  It seems like Javascript needs a couple new identity operators like `>==` and `<==`.  Although I am not sure that would make much sense, given the numerical implications of `>` and `<`.

This gives the expected result...

```
(null > 0 || null === 0);
```