# javascript equality returns false

Tags: javascript, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why `null >= 0 && null <= 0` but not `null == 0`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0)

All suppose to be true:

```
alert( "null==undefined:  " + (null == undefined) )
alert( "null==0:          " + (null == 0) )       // why false??
alert( "false=='':        " + (false == '') )
alert( "true==1:          " + (true == 1) )
alert( "true=='1':        " + (true == '1') )
alert( "'1'==1:           " + ('1' == 1) )
```

All suppose to be false:

```
alert( "null===undefined:  " + (null === undefined) )
alert( "null===0:          " + (null === 0) )  
alert( "false==='':        " + (false === '') )
alert( "true===1:          " + (true === 1) )
alert( "true==='1':        " + (true === '1') )
alert( "'1'===1:           " + ('1' === 1) )
```

Why  (null == 0) is false

I use last chrome to test it.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be `true`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0

Comment: Because `null` and `0` are not equivalent.

Comment: 0 is number.
null is null.

Comment: in this book https://github.com/spencertipping/js-in-ten-minutes/blob/master/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf on page 9, the author believes that this suppose to be true.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, you're reading a random book on GitHub instead of Crockford. :P

Comment: @Bergi Isn't it obvious why most people would expect that to be `true`? `null` clearly looks falsey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `null` type is not really comparable with the `number` type, so the [comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) returns `false`. From the spec (omitted the associative cases):

1. If the types are equal, use a type-specific comparison.
2. `null == undefined` is `true`
3. numbers and strings are compared as numbers, the string is converted
4. If a boolean is compared, it is converted to a number and compared again
5. If numbers or strings are compared with objects, the object is converted to a primitive and compared again - and no, [`Type(null)`](http://es5.github.com/#Type) is `Null`, not an object (as in the [`typeof` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3)).
6. For everything else, **`return false`**.

Comment: Exactly, it's [step 10 of the algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3). It seems `null` is only comparable with itself and `undefined`.

Comment: @bfavaretto `null` is an object, so it should be step 8 or 9, not 10.

Comment: But null is of type object. This isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear because `ToPrimitive(null)` apparently yields `null`.

Comment: @dystroy I believe no hint is passed in this case, as the spec says "If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object"/ So, which one would it pass? String or Number?

Comment: @bfavaretto Right, which *should* make the algorithm recurse infinitely. `compare(null, 0) -> compare(ToPrimitive(null), 0) -> compare(null, 0) -> …`

Comment: @kojiro I thought that too, and I'd really like to know the answer.

Comment: @kojiro, bfavaretto: `Type(Null)` is not `Object`, but `Null`.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, that settles the issue. So it goes straight to step 10 and returns `false`, no recursion.

Comment: So it boils down to an [even older JavaScript bug](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null).