# Is x >= y the same as x > y || x == y

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

When using NodeJS, I noticed:

```
null >= 0 // true
null > 0  // false
null == 0 // false
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0

Comment: @edotassi, that does answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: your title and your question are not exactly the same...

Comment: @PaulDraper try this: ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] == 10 // true