# With React Conditional Rendering, how to avoid 0 being counted as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following in my React components render function:

```
return (
  <div>
      {rating.score && (
       <div>do something</div>
      )}
  </div>
);
```

rating.score has `PropTypes.number`.

The above works great when the number is 1 or more. The problem is 0 is a valid rating. When 0 is the rating.score the above breaks. What is the right way to handle this react conditional rendering situation?

FYI, something like this does not work:

```
{(rating.score && rating.score >= 0) && (
  <div>do something</div>
)}
```

This does seem to work:

```
{skillRating.rating !== undefined && (
```

Is this the right thing to do here?

Comment: `rating` may be `null`. Try `skillRating.rating != null`.

Comment: `skillRating.rating !== undefined` should work fine

Answer (score 3):

Zero is NOT [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value in JavaScript.
This way you can render value that is 0 or more.

```js
return (
  <div>
      {rating.score > -1  && (
       <div>do something</div>
      )}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that `0` is a falsy value, it coerces to `false` in boolean context, however you can just check if the value is greater or equal to zero (assuming than negative values are not valid):

```
return (
  <div>
      {rating.score > 0 && (
       <div>do something</div>
      )}
  </div>
);
```

The condition on your edit doesn't work because in the expression `rating.score && rating.score >= 0`, the first operand, `rating.score` will be false.

Answer (score 1):

In case `rating.score` is guaranteed to be either `undefined` or a number, it's:

```
(rating.score >= 0) && (...)
```

Notice that the same doesn't apply to other falsy values [like `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0). In case there's a chance that it's falsy and not a number, this should become:

```
(rating.score === 0 || rating.score > 0) && (...)
```

This also benefits the readability (at least for developers who are aware of issues explained above) because the condition is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go about this and I can't say there is only one answer. One thing you might want to consider is using [`isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) global or `Number` methods i.e. `Number.isInteger()`.

In these cases you can help check that the number you are working with is a valid number and will help guard against `Infinty` or `NaN` (although `NaN` is a falsy value anyways).

The benefit of `isFinite` is it will also do the conversion of numbers that are casted to string so `"10"` would pass. Not sure if that's a concern.

```
{isFinite(rating.score) && (
  <div>do something</div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

My go-to in these situations is Boolean().

```
{Boolean(rating.score && rating.score >= 0) && (
  <div>do something</div>
)}
```