# Why does "null >= 0" evaluate to true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just discovered this oddity in JavaScript:

```js
null > 0
// false

null == 0
//false

null >= 0
//true
```

Why does the final test evaluate to true? It seems more than a little counterintuitive.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407544/why-is-null-in-javascript-bigger-than-1-less-than-1-but-not-equal-to-0#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=When%20you%20compare%20null%20for,%2C%20%3E%20%2C%20and%20%3E%3D%20.

Comment: Thanks both! I did search, did not find.

Comment: The >= operator behaves differently for some reason. The == operator converts null to undefined while comparing.

Comment: I am not certain, but I think it is spawned of laziness. It could be that the algorithm only perfoms one check. If null < 0 is false, then null >= 0 is true.