# null comparison with 0 not as expected as it showing the result with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

can someone explain the null comparison with 0

```js
null > 0 // false
null == 0 // false
null > 0 || null == 0 // false 

null >= 0 // true
```

why it happening ?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be happening? What is it specifically that surprises you about these results? Have you looked into what `null` is and how `>` and `==` work?

Comment: you can refer this.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910495/why-null-0-null-0-but-not-null-0)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript null isn't equal to 0 but equal to undefined.

```
null == undefined // true
```

Also :

> Strange result: null vs 0
>
> Let’s compare null with a zero:
>
> alert( null > 0 );  // (1) false
> alert( null == 0 ); // (2) false
> alert( null >= 0 ); // (3) true
>
> Mathematically, that’s strange. The
> last result states that "null is greater than or equal to zero", so in
> one of the comparisons above it must be true, but they are both false.
>
> The reason is that an equality check == and comparisons > < >= <= work
> differently. Comparisons convert null to a number, treating it as 0.
> That’s why (3) null >= 0 is true and (1) null > 0 is false.
>
> On the other hand, the equality check == for undefined and null is
> defined such that, without any conversions, they equal each other and
> don’t equal anything else. That’s why (2) null == 0 is false.

[Comparisons](https://javascript.info/comparison#strange-result-null-vs-0)

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that an equality check == and comparisons > < >= <= work differently. Comparisons convert null to a number, treating it as 0. That’s why null >= 0 is true and null > 0 is false.
>
> On the other hand, the equality check == for undefined and null is defined such that, without any conversions, they equal each other and don’t equal anything else. That’s why null == 0 is false.

Source: [Comparisons](https://javascript.info/comparison#strange-result-null-vs-0)